# Spring AOP:org.springframework.aop.support.NameMatchMethodPointcutAdvisor incompatible with Student

Tags: java, spring, spring-aop

I am learning spring AOP. Currently I am trying to create static point cut using NameMatchMehtodPointCut. But getting **NameMatchMethodPointcutAdvisor incompatible with Student**

Main method:

```
import org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanFactory;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanFactory;
import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.core.io.ClassPathResource;
import org.springframework.core.io.Resource;
public class Show {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    try{
        Resource resource=new ClassPathResource("applicationContext.xml");
        BeanFactory beanFactory= new XmlBeanFactory(resource);  
        /*Basic Spring */
        Student std=(Student) beanFactory.getBean("loggingAdvisor");
        String p=std.show();
        System.out.println(p);

    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
}
```

Application Context XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans  
               http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd">
    <bean name="student" class="Student" autowire="byType">
        <!-- <constructor-arg name="std_id" value="2212" /> <constructor-arg name="name" 
            value="Raj" /> -->
        <property name="std_id" value="2734"/>
        <property name="name" value="Sujit"/>
    </bean>
    <bean name="address" class="Address">
        <!-- <constructor-arg name="street" value="2734" /> <constructor-arg name="city" 
            value="BBSR" /> <constructor-arg name="zip" value="560100" /> -->
        <property name="street" value="2734" />
        <property name="city" value="BBSR" />
        <property name="zip" value="560100" />
    </bean>
    <bean name='loggingAOP' class="LoggingAOP"/>
    <bean name="AOPDemo" class="org.springframework.aop.framework.ProxyFactoryBean">
    <property name="target" ref="student"/>
    <property name="interceptorNames">
    <list><value>loggingAOP</value></list>
    </property>
    </bean>
    <bean id="loggingAdvisor" class="org.springframework.aop.support.NameMatchMethodPointcutAdvisor">
    <property name="advice" ref="loggingAOP"></property>
    <property name="mappedName"><value>show</value></property>
    </bean>
<!--    <bean name="mypointcut" class="org.springframework.aop.support.NameMatchMethodPointcut">
    <property name="mappedName"><value>show</value></property>
    </bean> -->
</beans>
```

**LoggingAOP.java**

```
import java.lang.reflect.Method;
import org.springframework.aop.support.DefaultPointcutAdvisor;


import java.sql.Array;

import org.aopalliance.intercept.MethodInterceptor;
import org.aopalliance.intercept.MethodInvocation;
import org.springframework.aop.AfterReturningAdvice;
import org.springframework.aop.MethodBeforeAdvice;
import org.springframework.aop.ThrowsAdvice;


public class LoggingAOP implements MethodBeforeAdvice , AfterReturningAdvice, ThrowsAdvice, MethodInterceptor{

    public void before(Method m,Object[] args,Object target)
    {
        System.out.println("Current Method is"+m.getName());
        System.out.println(target.getClass());
    }
    public void  afterReturning(Object returnValue, Method method, Object[] args, Object target) {
         System.out.println("It is over!!!");

    }
    public void afterThrowing(Exception e) throws Throwable
    {
        System.out.println("throwing exception from Sujit Demo");
    }

    public Object invoke(MethodInvocation in) throws Throwable
    {
        Object obj=in.proceed();
        try{
        if(obj.equals("This is Student"))
            return "Matching";
        else
            return "Not matching";
        }
        catch(Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return obj;
    }

}
```

I have POJO classes of Student and Address.

Please help me out!!

Comment: You are getting the bean named `loggingAdvisor` which is of type `NameMatchMethodPointcutAdvisor` how do you expect that magically to become a `Student` (as that is what you are casting it to). Also even if you wold get the student it wouldn't work as you would need an `ApplicationContext` instead of a `BeanFactory`.

Comment: If I provide below details with applicationContext it works even the return type is of org.springframework.aop.framework.ProxyFactoryBean.                                                                            ApplicationContext applicationContext=new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("applicationContext.xml");
  Student std=(Student) applicationContext.getBean("AOPDemo");

Comment: But issue comes when I try to retrieve using org.springframework.aop.support.NameMatchMethodPointcutAdvisor.     Is there any way other way to retrieve above?

Comment: The bean `AOPDemo` is a `FactoryBean` which produces `Student` beans so yes it would work that way. You cannot get a `PointcutAdvisor` and expect it to be a `Student`... That isn't how AOP nor Java works. Instead of hacking and not understanding read the reference guide and follow a tutorial (or book) explaining the concepts.